# why python pandas round results in object

Tags: numpy, pandas, types

In the following line, the dtype of `INDATUMA` is int64. Why does the resulting Series have dtype object?

```
all_treatments['year'] = (all_treatments['INDATUMA'] / 10000).round
```

I think `pandas.Series.round` is just `numpy.around` cast to each element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget `()`, so `round` return `method Series.round`:

```
all_treatments['year'] = (all_treatments['INDATUMA'] / 10000).round()
```

Sample:

```
print all_treatments
   INDATUMA   A  C  D
0     17030   5  a  2
1     72020   9  a  b
2     28279  10  c  d
3     32037   2  c  c

all_treatments['year'] = (all_treatments['INDATUMA'] / 10000).round
print all_treatments
   INDATUMA   A  C  D                                               year
0     17030   5  a  2  <bound method Series.round of 0    1.7030\n1  ...
1     72020   9  a  b  <bound method Series.round of 0    1.7030\n1  ...
2     28279  10  c  d  <bound method Series.round of 0    1.7030\n1  ...
3     32037   2  c  c  <bound method Series.round of 0    1.7030\n1  ...

all_treatments['year'] = (all_treatments['INDATUMA'] / 10000).round()
print all_treatments
   INDATUMA   A  C  D  year
0     17030   5  a  2     2
1     72020   9  a  b     7
2     28279  10  c  d     3
3     32037   2  c  c     3
```